# Delete grid elements - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, cell

I was "experimenting" new things with tkinter (i am a beginner with it) and i made, only for fun obviously, this application :

```
from tkinter import *

def text() :
    if checking :
        content.grid_forget()
    else :
        content = Label(root, text = txt.get()).grid(row = 3, column = 0) 

def check() :
    checking = True
    text()

root = Tk()

txt = StringVar()
checking = False

bt1 = Button(root, text = "Print me!", command = text)
bt2 = Button(root, text = "Clear!", command = check)
txt1 = Entry(root, textvariable = txt)

row = 0
for i in [bt1, bt2, txt1] :
    i.grid(row = row, column = 0)
    row+=1

root.mainloop()
```

My question is, why isn't the "clear" button working?

Comment: `checking` is a local variable inside `check`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your app, you might want to consider rethinking the structure and your widget management. please consider reading (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) and check other posts on stackoverflow and make sure you check @Bryan Oakley past and present comments.

You are using local variables as he mentioned, this is easily corrected by declaring it as global as follows:

```
global variable_name
```

in your code,

additionally, you might want to consider restructuring your content ("label") when you add it to your root window:
from:

```
content = Label(root, text = txt.get()).grid(row = 3, column = 0)
```

to:

```
content = Label(root, text = txt.get())
content.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
```

if you are not sure of what is going on , consider adding print() to your code, here is a quick snippet:

```
def text() :
    global content
    print(root.grid_slaves())
    if checking :
        content = Label(root, text = txt.get())
        content.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
```

you will immediately see that every time you click on print me, widgets are added to your layout.

best practices for your layout ([Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application))

Quick Hint:

```
def text() :
    print(checking)
    if checking :
        content.grid_forget()
    else :
        content = Label(root, text = txt.get()).grid(row = 3, column = 0) 

def check() :
    checking = True
    text()

root = Tk()

txt = StringVar()
checking = False
```

checking is always False... you might consider rethinking some logic as well